# Removing meta data in R

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I have  a corpus consisting of newspaper columns;

```
library(tm)
inspect(corpus8)
[[69]]
<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
rec: 60  col: r3 ?investigate time, place, relationships and measurement concepts in < Aboriginal > and Torres Strait Islander contexts?. Add family breakdown, 

str(corpus8)
List of 71
 $ 1 :List of 2
  ..$ content: chr "rec: 7  col: r3 by dancing at a free concert and that dysfunction is fixed by changing the constitution to "
  ..$ meta   :List of 7
  .. ..$ author       : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ datetimestamp: POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2015-03-04 08:17:37"
  .. ..$ description  : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ heading      : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ id           : chr "1"
  .. ..$ language     : chr "en"
  .. ..$ origin       : chr(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "TextDocumentMeta"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "PlainTextDocument" "TextDocument"
```

I am hoping for advice regarding R code so as to remove this metadata prior to undertaking an analysis. The only visible text takes the form:

```
rec: 6  col: r3
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried, for example, meta(corpus[[1]]) <- NULL? to remove the author meta content?  Or meta(corpus[[1]]) <- ""

Comment: Many thanks. No I hadn't. I did just try the first option. I'm not sure what additional code I'm being prompted to add.

        > meta(corpus[[corpus]]) <- NULL? 
    After more thought, tonight I used the following so at least the term document matrix will not include these terms:

       corpus <- tm_map (corpus, removeWords, c("rec", "col", "r3", "  r "))
       corpus <-tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
       corpus <-tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
       corpus <-tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)

Bob

Comment: Oh!  When you said meta data I took that as the technical term metadata.  You want to remove certain words from your text set?  You should use the methods to remove stopwords and supplement the stopword list (usually "English" but sometimes broadened to "SMART" with your own words.  Is that your intention?  I can put it in an answer.

Comment: Thanks.  If I go back to my original post (above), output from using the str and inspect commands applied to my corpus are displayed. A naive question, do these results suggest metadata in the technical sense?   Bob

Comment: I think what you want is to remove certain words from the content element list corpus8.  The remaining meta items of that list probably don't matter to you, so you can leave them alone.  You did the right approach with removeWords, stripWhitespace, and removeNumbers.  Many people doing text mining also remove punctuation, btw.  You can create additional words to remove if you create a vector and add that to removeWords.  Am I helping or is this confusing you?

Comment: Your confirmation is useful. Thanks